# Fetch part of a JSONB document while keeping structure intact

Tags: postgresql

I am quiet new to Postgres and I am looking for a way to fetch only a part of a jsonb document while keeping the structure intact.

My table posts have the structure:

```
id: PK,
status: enum
content: jsonb
```

The content document contains the post content in several languages:

```
{
  "fr": {},
  "en": {},
  "es": {}
}
```

I am trying to select a post while keeping only one key in content: `{ id, status, content:

```
{
  "fr": {}
}
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT id, status, content -> 'fr' as 'content FROM posts
```

but the fr key was missing in the content.

Then I tried to use the function `json_build_object`:

```
SELECT id, status, json_build_object('fr', content -> 'fr') AS 'content' FROM posts
```

but without any success.

Comment: I finally found the problem... Just some wrong quotes. Here is the good request: `SELECT "id", "status", json_build_object('fr', "content" -> 'fr') AS "content" FROM "posts";`

Comment: @RichChurcher Instead of editing, just vote to close as a (confirmed) typo

Comment: Fair call! Sorry, I was in 'automatic' mode.